# subscription is missing properties from observable<character[]>

Tags: angular, observable, subscription

i cant fix the error, "Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Character[]>';......
any help fixing the error would be nice.  i also need help converting api returns to useable data.

```
export class CharacterSearchComponent implements OnInit {

  // sets characters$ as an observable
  character$: Observable<Character[]>;
  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  // sets private method for searching
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(
    // sets private method for using character.service
    private characterService: CharacterService
  ) { }

  // pushes search terms into the observable
  search(term: string): void{
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.character$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      // wait after keystroacks to reduce frequent http pull attempts
      debounceTime(300),

      // ignore if same as previous turm
      distinctUntilChanged(),

      // switch to new search if the term changed
      switchMap((term: string) => this.characterService.searchChar(term)),
    ).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
  }

}
```

edit, added in definition for this.characterService.searchChar(term)),

```
    searchChar(term: string): Observable<Character[]> {
      if (!term.trim()) {
        // if no match, return nothing
        return of([]);
        //console.log();
      }

     
      return this.http.get<Character[]>(`${this.characterUrl}/?search=${term}`).pipe(tap(x => x.length?
        this.log(`found characters matching "${term}"`) :
        this.log(`Sorry, cant find a character matching "${term}"`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<Character[]>('searchChar', [])));
    }
```

Comment: please provide the definition of `this.characterService.searchChar(term)`

Comment: searchChar(term: string): Observable<Character[]> {
      if (!term.trim()) {
        // if no match, return nothing
        return of([]);
        //console.log();
      }

     
      return this.http.get<Character[]>(`${this.characterUrl}/?search=${term}`).pipe(tap(x => x.length?
        this.log(`found characters matching "${term}"`) :
        this.log(`Sorry, cant find a character matching "${term}"`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<Character[]>('searchChar', [])));
    }

Answer (score 1):

you've defined `character$` as an `Observable`, but you're assigning a subscription.

```
this.character$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
  // wait after keystroacks to reduce frequent http pull attempts
  debounceTime(300),

  // ignore if same as previous turm
  distinctUntilChanged(),

  // switch to new search if the term changed
  switchMap((term: string) => this.characterService.searchChar(term)),
)

this.character$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

would work. when you call `subscribe` it returns a `Subscription` object. You should assign the `Observable` first if you want to, and then subscribe to it after the fact if needed.